# thread started in javaagent blocking exit

Tags: java, javaagents

In my javagent, I started a HttpServer:

```
public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws InstantiationException, IOException {

        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);

        server.createContext("/report", new ReportHandler());
        server.createContext("/data", new DataHandler());
        server.createContext("/stack", new StackHandler());
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
            int count = 0;
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.setDaemon(true);
                t.setName("JDBCLD-HTTP-SERVER" + count++);
                return t;
            }
            
        });
        server.setExecutor(es);
        server.start();

        // how to properly close ?
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                server.stop(5);
                log.info("internal httpserver has been closed.");
                es.shutdown();
                try {
                    if (!es.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        log.warn("executor service of internal httpserver not closing in 60 seconds");
                        es.shutdownNow();
                        if (!es.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                            log.error("executor service of internal httpserver not closing in 120 seconds, give up");
                    }else {
                        log.info("executor service of internal httpserver closed.");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    log.warn("thread interrupted, shutdown executor service of internal httpserver");
                    es.shutdownNow();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });

    // other instrumention code ignored ...
}
```

testing programe:

```
public class AgentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.31.27.182:1521/pas");
        config.setUsername("pas");
        config.setPassword("pas");

        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
        Connection c = ds.getConnection();
        Connection c1 = ds.getConnection();
        
        c.getMetaData();
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            c.close();
            c1.close();
            ds.close();
        }
        
        c.close();
        c1.close();
        
        ds.close();
        
        
    }

}
```

When target jvm exit, I want the to stop that HttpServer. but when  my testing java programe finish, main thread stoped but the whole jvm process won't terminate, shutdown hook in above code won't execute. if I click 'terminate' button in eclipse IDE, eclipse will show a error:
[image]
but at least jvm will exit, and my shutdown hook get invoked.

according to the java doc of `java.lang.Runtime`:

> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of
> events:
>
> The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or
> when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or The
> virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as
> typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system
> shutdown.

`com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` will started a non-daemon dispatcher thread, that thread will exit when `HttpServer#stop` get called, so I am facing a deadlock.

> non-daemon thread not finish -> shutdown hook not triggered -> can't
> stop server -> non-daemon thread not finish

Any good idea? please note I can't modify code of targeting application.

### UPDATES after apply kriegaex's answer

```
I added some logging to watch dog thread, and here is outputs:

2021-09-22 17:30:00.967 INFO  - Connnection@1594791957 acquired by 40A4F128987F8BD9C0EE6749895D1237
2021-09-22 17:30:00.968 DEBUG - Stack@40A4F128987F8BD9C0EE6749895D1237: 
java.lang.Throwable: 
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.<init>(ProxyConnection.java:102)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.<init>(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyFactory.getProxyConnection(ProxyFactory.java)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolEntry.createProxyConnection(PoolEntry.java:97)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:192)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
    at agenttest.AgentTest.main(AgentTest.java:19)
2021-09-22 17:30:00.969 INFO  - Connnection@686560878 acquired by 464555C270688B747CA211DE489B7730
2021-09-22 17:30:00.969 DEBUG - Stack@464555C270688B747CA211DE489B7730: 
java.lang.Throwable: 
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.<init>(ProxyConnection.java:102)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.<init>(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyFactory.getProxyConnection(ProxyFactory.java)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolEntry.createProxyConnection(PoolEntry.java:97)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:192)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
    at agenttest.AgentTest.main(AgentTest.java:20)
2021-09-22 17:30:00.971 DEBUG - Connnection@1594791957 used by getMetaData
2021-09-22 17:30:01.956 DEBUG - there is still 12 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:01.956 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true main#false server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true HikariPool-1 housekeeper#true HikariPool-1 connection adder#true 
2021-09-22 17:30:02.956 DEBUG - there is still 12 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:02.956 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true main#false server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true HikariPool-1 housekeeper#true HikariPool-1 connection adder#true 
2021-09-22 17:30:03.957 DEBUG - there is still 12 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:03.957 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true main#false server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true HikariPool-1 housekeeper#true HikariPool-1 connection adder#true 
2021-09-22 17:30:04.959 DEBUG - there is still 12 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:04.959 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true main#false server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true HikariPool-1 housekeeper#true HikariPool-1 connection adder#true 
2021-09-22 17:30:05.959 DEBUG - there is still 12 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:05.960 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true main#false server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true HikariPool-1 housekeeper#true HikariPool-1 connection adder#true 
2021-09-22 17:30:06.960 DEBUG - there is still 11 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:06.960 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true main#false server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true HikariPool-1 housekeeper#true 
2021-09-22 17:30:07.961 DEBUG - there is still 11 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:07.961 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true main#false server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true HikariPool-1 housekeeper#true 
2021-09-22 17:30:08.961 DEBUG - there is still 11 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:08.961 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true main#false server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true HikariPool-1 housekeeper#true 
2021-09-22 17:30:09.962 DEBUG - there is still 11 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:09.962 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true main#false server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true HikariPool-1 housekeeper#true 
2021-09-22 17:30:10.962 DEBUG - there is still 11 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:10.963 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true main#false server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true HikariPool-1 housekeeper#true 
2021-09-22 17:30:10.976 INFO  - Connnection@1594791957 released
2021-09-22 17:30:10.976 DEBUG - set connection count to 0 by stack hash 40A4F128987F8BD9C0EE6749895D1237
2021-09-22 17:30:10.976 INFO  - Connnection@686560878 released
2021-09-22 17:30:10.976 DEBUG - set connection count to 0 by stack hash 464555C270688B747CA211DE489B7730
2021-09-22 17:30:11.963 DEBUG - there is still 10 active threads, keep wathcing
2021-09-22 17:30:11.963 DEBUG - Reference Handler#true Finalizer#true Signal Dispatcher#true server-timer#true Thread-2#false jdbcld-watch-dog#false Timer-0#true oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser#true InterruptTimer#true DestroyJavaVM#false 
2021-09-22 17:30:12.964 DEBUG - there is still 10 active threads, keep wathcing
```

---

**updates**

I want to support all kinds of java application, include web application running with servlet containers and standard alone javase applications.

Comment: It is dirty, but you could start a background thread that checks all threads to see how many non-daemon threads there are every now and then. If it detects that only the http server thread remains, it can close the web server, thus stopping the program.

Comment: @kriegaex thanks for your effort, I was busy refactoring main logic of my agent recent days, I sure will try your approach and feedback, we are in a national vacation, so please wait for somedays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating *ewrammer*'s idea. I used the little `byte-buddy-agent` helper library for dynamically attaching an agent in order to make my example self-contained, starting the Java agent right from the main method. I omitted the 3 trivial no-op dummy handler classes necessary to run this example.

```java
package org.acme.agent;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Agent {

  public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws IOException {
    HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    ExecutorService executorService = getExecutorService(httpServer);
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(getShutdownHook(httpServer, executorService));
    // other instrumention code ignored ...
    startWatchDog();
  }

  private static ExecutorService getExecutorService(HttpServer server) {
    server.createContext("/report", new ReportHandler());
    server.createContext("/data", new DataHandler());
    server.createContext("/stack", new StackHandler());
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
      int count = 0;

      @Override
      public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.setName("JDBCLD-HTTP-SERVER" + count++);
        return t;
      }

    });
    server.setExecutor(executorService);
    server.start();
    return executorService;
  }

  private static Thread getShutdownHook(HttpServer httpServer, ExecutorService executorService) {
    return new Thread(() -> {
      httpServer.stop(5);
      System.out.println("Internal HTTP server has been stopped");
      executorService.shutdown();
      try {
        if (!executorService.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
          System.out.println("Executor service of internal HTTP server not closing in 60 seconds");
          executorService.shutdownNow();
          if (!executorService.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            System.out.println("Executor service of internal HTTP server not closing in 120 seconds, giving up");
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Executor service of internal HTTP server closed");
        }
      }
      catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        System.out.println("Thread interrupted, shutting down executor service of internal HTTP server");
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    });
  }

  private static void startWatchDog() {
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
    while (threadGroup.getParent() != null)
      threadGroup = threadGroup.getParent();
    final ThreadGroup topLevelThreadGroup = threadGroup;
    // Plus 1, because of the monitoring thread we are going to start right below
    final int activeCount = topLevelThreadGroup.activeCount() + 1;

    new Thread(() -> {
      do {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
      } while (topLevelThreadGroup.activeCount() > activeCount);
      System.exit(0);
    }).start();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    premain(null, ByteBuddyAgent.install());
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      new Thread(() -> {
        int threadDurationSeconds = 1 + random.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("Starting thread with duration " + threadDurationSeconds + " s");
        try {
          Thread.sleep(threadDurationSeconds * 1000);
          System.out.println("Finishing thread after " + threadDurationSeconds + " s");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
      }).start();
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, this is basically your example code, refactored into a few helper methods for readability, plus the new watchdog method. It is quite straightforward.

This produces a console log like:

```
Starting thread with duration 6 s
Starting thread with duration 6 s
Starting thread with duration 8 s
Starting thread with duration 7 s
Starting thread with duration 5 s
Finishing thread after 5 s
Finishing thread after 6 s
Finishing thread after 6 s
Finishing thread after 7 s
Finishing thread after 8 s
internal httpserver has been closed.
executor service of internal httpserver closed.
```

Comment: not working with real world use case, see my edits.

Comment: Your use case is not a real-world use case, because there is no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem. I however posted an MCVE proving that it works as suggested. How am I expected to understand your code by just looking at log output generated by code I cannot see? Please publish an MCVE on GitHub, then I can take a look. Probably you simply did not adjust my code to your situation correctly - no reason not to accept my answer.

Comment: it's just the testing programe in my question, I tested your code, it works. but when running my testing programe with '-javaagent:xxxx=args', it don't work

Comment: Why can't we just check if main thread exists

Comment: What was unclear about the term MCVE? Please publish something on GitHub, I need to reproduce your problem if you want my help on your follow-up question. Your log does not even explain what is wrong after you claim to have applied my changes. Please either provide me with an MCVE or accept and upvote my answer, because it solves the problem as stated by you in this question, then ask a new question. I cannot say anything intelligent about your code if I cannot see and run it.

Comment: As for the "check if main thread exists" question, you did not ask about that before. Of course you could do that, but the solution would be specific to your program and not generic as you requested. Now you are throwing in a new question about web apps in servlet containers, i.e. moving the target of the question. This is a Q/A platform, not a discussion forum. Garbage in, garbage out, i.e. unclear or generic questions yield unclear or generic answers. But I still claim that this answer solves the problem stated in your initial version of the question.